# Save request body in Redis

Tags: go, redis

I got an issue with my caching in Redis. I have endpoints which I use multiple times but with different request body, as I only found a way to cache based on request URL I get the cache only for my first request, the next ones even if they have a different body are not cached also.
So my question is how I can properly cache my requests by taking into consideration different request body for the same endpoint?

I tried to hash the request body and add it as a key but it has some errors with hashing JSON.

This is how I cache at the moment:

```
// Store the response in Redis                
err = rdb.Set(
  context.Background(),
  c.Request.URL.RequestURI(),
  responseBody,
  5*time.Minute
).Err()

if err != nil {
  fmt.Println("Error caching data in Redis:", err)
}
```

```
// Check if the response is cached in Redis
cachedResponse, err := rdb.Get(
  context.Background(),
  c.Request.URL.RequestURI()
).Result()

if err == nil {
  c.Data(
    http.StatusOK,
    "application/json", 
    []byte(cachedResponse)
  )
  return
}
```